# Running Tomcat in fedora 14

Tags: java, tomcat

I downloaded and installed tomcat in my system(fedora 14) and when I try to run tomcat I get an error, please tell me where could be wrong, following is my .bash_profile settings

```
# User specific environment and startup programs
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin

#java 1.7
export JAVA_HOME=/home/harsha/Applications/jdk1.7.0
export JDK_HOME=/home/harsha/Applications/jdk1.7.0
export JRE_HOME=/home/harsha/Applications/jdk1.7.0

#maven
export M2_HOME=/home/harsha/Applications/apache-maven-2.2.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

#Ant
export ANT_HOME=/home/harsha/installedApps/apache-ant-1.8.2/

#tomcat
export CATALINA_BASE=/home/harsha/Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/harsha/Applicaations/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/
export CATALINA_TMPDIR=/home/harsha/Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/temp



export PATH=$HOME/bin:$M2:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JDK_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and when I try to run ./startup.sh I get following error,

```
Cannot find /home/harsha/Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.22//bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program
```

Comment: You really should not set the CATALINE_XXX env variables, let Tomcat handle those.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the final slash in the `CATALINA_` variables.